# How to install Kali Linux without CD and flash drive?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, kali-linux

I have download Kali Linux. But the size is too large for my flash drive, my flash drive is 1.8gb and the Kali Linux iso is 2.3gb.
I use an Asus eeepc 1215p which has no CD/DVD drive.

My machine was installed with Ubuntu 12.04, and I've an empty partition.
I want to install Kali Linux onto that partition, but I don't understand how?

Can anyone here tell me how to install Kali Linux without a CD/DVD drive and flash drive ?
I heard about poor man, I was searching for it, but I only found a lot for PCLinux OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be more direct ways, but one thing you can do is:

1) Prepare an installation in a virtual machine under Ubuntu 12.04. This can be done from a downloaded installation image of Kali Linux.

2) Once you have a VM setup, format the emtpy partition, mount it and tell the VM control application to make that available to the Kali VM (or mount the Kali VM disc directly in your os, if that is supported).

3) Copy all the files so that the root of the Kali VM gets to the base of the mounted empty partition. ( something like `find / -print0 | cpio -pdmv0 /mnt/new_disc`).

4) Adjust the mount points in /etc/fstab on the target partition (adjusting /dev/sdXY names or UUIDS as necessary)

5) Run `grub-mkconfig` under Ubuntu, check the output for Kali being recognised. If so write the output to `/boot/boot/grub.cfg`  and after a reboot Kali should be available in the startup men and bootable.

I have done exactly this using VirtualBox to prepare a remote upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 (prepared on a 12.04 box), but there is nothing very special about the procedure that other VM software could not be used.

(With VMware—which I used from 1999 until switching to using VirtualBox—you could directly use an existing partition as drive for the virtual machine. VirtualBox might be able to do that as well, that would do away with step 3 and possible 4)

Comment: hi, thanks for the respon, i was use virtual box to test kali.iso, but as we know. my machine is very limited. limited with ram and video graphic, so i cant long to take kali in vbox,  by the way, i'll try your option. thanks :)

Comment: @AnggaMovic This is not the quickest way. If you are good with the commandline you might run Kali in non-graphics mode and safe a lot of ram in the VM. Maybe buying a bigger USB stick is the quicker (and thereby cheaper) solution.

Comment: i amt not expert in command line, but i know how to used CLI, i have a bigger USB stick, but for now i 
just bring the little one. yap, the quicker is to buying / get back to home for take my USB stick, but from the beginning I wanted to know how poorman work with non PClinuxos distro(s). but thanks :)